# When using surveys in SharePoint 2010 - do the end users with contribute access see the results?

Tags: permissions

When using surveys in SharePoint 2010 - do the end users with contribute access see the results? Do they see the link for Show all responses? If they do is there a way to block that. I want to be able to afford them some annonymity.

Answer (score 1):

By default Contribute [permission level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbasepermissions.aspx) has the following List permissions options enabled:

- *View Items* - View items in lists and documents in document libraries
- *View Application Pages* - View forms, views, and application pages. Enumerate lists

It means that users could read **all responses** using links for survey views (Show all responses, Show all responses)

But, using Item-level Permissions setting it could be configured to read responses that were created by the user.

### Configure Item-level Permissions

Select Survey List, click Settings menu -> Survey settings -> Advanced Settings.
Select *Read responses that were created by the user*  under Item-level Permissions section as shown on picture below

[image]